# Comparing two files in BASH line by line

Tags: string, bash, awk, grep, comparison

I need to make a script file that reads two files and prints out common lines between them. I know that both the files are the same number of lines and each line only contains one word.

File 1:

```
Blue
Red
Orange
Green
Yellow
Blue
```

File 2:

```
Blue
Green
Red
Purple
Yellow
Blue
```

Expected output:

```
Blue
Yellow
Blue
```

So in the example Red and Green appear in both files, however they are not on the same line in each file so they are ignored.

Have tried using awk, grep and comm but couldn't get them to work.

Trying to find the solution that takes the shortest amount of time to process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { lines[NR] = $0 } NR != FNR && lines[FNR] == $0 { print }' file1 file2
```

Explanation:

- When reading the first file (`NR == FNR`), build a mapping of line number to value
- When reading not the first file (`NR != FNR`), if the current line matches what the corresponding line has in the cache, then print the line

This reads both files exactly once,
and uses roughly as much memory as the size of the first file.

Answer (score 4):

With paste and GNU grep. Step by step.

```
paste -d '|' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Blue|Blue
Red|Green
Orange|Red
Green|Purple
Yellow|Yellow
Blue|Blue
```

---

```
paste -d '|' file1 file2 | grep -Po '^(.*)\|+\1$'
```

Output:

```
Blue|Blue
Yellow|Yellow
Blue|Blue
```

---

With `\K`:

```
paste -d '|' file1 file2 | grep -Po '^(.*)\|+\K\1$'
```

Output:

```
Blue
Yellow
Blue
```

I assume `|` is not in your files.

Comment: Nice touch with `\K`. Btw, if you're already using PCRE, you can shorten it to `paste file1 file2 | grep -Po '(.*)\t\K\1$'`, since `paste` uses tab by default.

Answer (score 2):

With `paste` and `awk`:

```
paste -d'|' file1 file2 | awk -F'|' '$1==$2 {print $1}'
```

I like the use of `paste` from @Cyrus, but I think the comparison of the merged lines is easier to undertand with `awk`. In this case `-F` takes care of using the same separator `|` and it is very simple to compare the first bit `$1` with the second `$2`. The output could be either one.

It is also assumed that `|` is not part of the input files. Any other character may be chosen instead.

If each line of the input files contains only one word, this will be shorter and also work:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '$1==$2 {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more way,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR,$1];next}(FNR,$1) in a' file1 file2
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat f1
Blue
Red
Orange
Green
Yellow
Blue

$ cat f2
Blue
Green
Red
Purple
Yellow
Blue

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR,$1];next}(FNR,$1) in a' f1 f2
Blue
Yellow
Blue
```